# Binding data to a django form ChoiceField's options for rendering

Tags: django, django-templates, django-forms

I have a form (generated by a form factory) with a special field

```
def MyFormGenerator(data):
    CHOICES = <created_using_data_value>
    class MyForm(form.Form):
        myfield = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect)
    return MyForm
```

What I need to do is bind some python variables to each choice so that the template can use them at render time (each choice will be laid out in a div with details about that choice).

I can think of 2 ways to do this. (#1 is preferred for flexibility sake)
1) Give the template a separate list of what fields should appear (with the data included) and have the template grab and render each field as it needs them.
2) Have the data tied to the field so the template can grab and use it while iterating.

I can *almost* do #1 (manually creating the input field in the template), but I can't figure out how to call out a field choice by name using a variable since it's difficult to know what the  doesn't work when _some_field_ is a template variable.

Right now I am literally re-creating the field from SCRATCH in the template (recreating the choice values, etc) but this is far from ideal.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by the data for the field? [labels](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/#customizing-the-form-template)?  [help_text](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/fields/#help-text) on the model? Or something from a previous page of forms? Can you post your current form or mock up what you want?

Comment: Sorry, I kind of worded that wrong, I actually need data for each option of a choice (radio-buttons) field. The field if for selecting a shipping method (ground, usps, etc) and I need to attach some data to each option that the template can use. The data would consist of a dictionary of values such as expected arrival date, cost, descriptions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Django's MultipleModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/fields/#modelmultiplechoicefield) for forms.

It allows you to use querysets of another model as your choice_fields. If your choices are going to have so much data on them, they may be better off having their own model anyway.
This will work assuming there is some sort of way to query what results you want to show up, even if you assign an integerfield to them for common groupings. Worst case you just have some giant queries (in code length) with many excludes, filters, etc.

```
field1 = forms.MultipleModelChoiceField(queryset=MyModel.objects.filter(method="UPS"), empty_label="(None)")
```

It uses the SelectMultiple widget by default but it can be overridden with a kwarg.

Comment: This would work, except that the choices are not specific to one table. The site uses a plugin system (with a registration module for apps to register a class into) and you are picking 1 option out of various options offered by any one of the plugins.

It is for a shipping selection and there are multiple shipping modlues (flat rate, canada post, usps, etc) and each one has different options (10 day flat-rate, next-day flat rate, canada post expedited, etc). The user needs to pick a single option out all those available.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I've found to do this is to attach the data in the view instead of to the choice field itself.

For example if you have a list `choices_data` the same length as your choices and you want to bind each piece of data to a corresponding choice you can do something like the following.

```
def my_view(request):
    form = MyForm()
    myfield_choices = zip(form['myfield'], choices_data)
    ...
```

Then you can loop through the choices in your template like this:

```
{% for choice, data in myfield_choices %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```